# jQuery: using dinamically generated variables as selector to append JSON input as content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I am working on a site that is basically a list of items separated by categories. The user can add a category entering the name into the following form:

```
    <form onsubmit="append_div(); add_cat(); return false;"> 
        <input id="new_category"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" id="add_btn_category" />
    </form>
```

Two functions are called, `append_div()`, which dinamically creates a new child where the new category will be inserted, and `add_cat()`, which gets JSON from the server and should set the new content in the indicated selector.

```
    function append_div(){
            var nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("h3").length; 
            var node = document.createElement("h3");
            node.id = "new_space" + nodelist;
            var new_sp = "'#new_space" + nodelist + "'"; // to be used in selector
            node.className= "categories";
            document.getElementById("append").appendChild(node);
        }

    function add_cat() {
            var url = 'add_category.php?category=' + $('#new_category').val();
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                $(new_sp).html(data[0].category);
            });
        }
```

Everything works except `$(new_sp).html(data[0].category);`. This is the code generated entering three different categories: `aa`, `bb` and `cc`.

```
    `<div id="append">
        <h3 id="new_space0" class="categories"></h3>
        <h3 id="new_space1" class="categories"></h3>
        <h3 id="new_space2" class="categories"></h3>
    </div>`
```

But it should be:

```
        `<div id="append">
            <h3 id="new_space0" class="categories">aa</h3>
            <h3 id="new_space1" class="categories">bb</h3>
            <h3 id="new_space2" class="categories">cc</h3>
        </div>`
```

Using the variable `new_sp` as a selector in `$(new_sp).html(data[0].category);` doesn't seem to work, but after checking posts with similar problems and trying many of the proposed solutions I could not solve the it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var new_sp = "'#new_space" + nodelist + "'"; // to be used in selector
```

should be

```
var new_sp = "#" + node.id; // to be used in selector
```

and the variable `new_sp` should defined outside the function `append_div` or it should be `global` to access in the function `add_cat`

Something like

```
   var new_sp = "";
   function append_div(){
            var nodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("h3").length; 
            var node = document.createElement("h3");
            node.id = "new_space" + nodelist;
            new_sp = "#" + node.id; // to be used in selector
            node.className= "categories";
            document.getElementById("append").appendChild(node);
        }

    function add_cat() {
            var url = 'add_category.php?category=' + $('#new_category').val();
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                $(new_sp).html(data[0].category);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I already tried before to define `new_sp` your way, but the problem was with the scope.